# angle axis to Quaternion using Eigen

Tags: eigen, quaternions

I need to convert an angle axis representation to a Quaternion using Eigen

For example I have the following angle axis representation of a pose from a UR robot (rotation part of the pose of the robot only)

(-2.237 -2.217 -0.030)

I want to convert this to a Quaternion using Eigen

I tried this code

```
Eigen::Quaterniond q;
  q = AngleAxisd(-2.237, Vector3d::UnitX())
      * AngleAxisd(-2.217, Vector3d::UnitY())
      * AngleAxisd(-0.030, Vector3d::UnitZ());
```

but I end up with

```
qx: -3.9853142115731549e-01
qy: -4.0057160431638472e-01
qz: 7.9758941987327925e-01
qw: 2.1110711374071198e-01
```

When I use this online conversion tool I get something different

https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Do you need scaled-axis to quaternion conversion? Try `q = AngleAxisd(v.normalized(), v.norm());` (and verify, that this also works for `v.norm()==0` ...)

Answer (score 3):

Managed to get it sorted this way

```
  Eigen::Quaterniond q(Eigen::AngleAxisd(angle, axis));
```